# Finding the Java compiler used by Ant

Tags: java, ant, javac

We are using a product that comes with it's own SDK. This SDK contains:

- It's own JRE installation
- It's own Ant installation
- A few Ant scripts for building stuff
- A few batch scripts that call Ant with the included scripts

Now some of the Ant scripts compile Java code, using the `javac` task. Now I'd like to find the `javac` executable that is used for that. I have checked the following:

- The batch scripts are temporarily setting `JAVA_HOME` to the included JRE. The whole thing works without having another JDK installed.
- The included JRE is a JRE and not a JDK. So there is no `javac.exe` to be found.
- There is no `javac.exe` included anywhere else in the SDK.
- `build.compiler` doesn't seem to be set anywhere in the Ant scripts.
- The `fork`, `executable` and `compiler` attributes are not set on any of the `javac` tasks.

I'm out of ideas on where to look. What other possibility is there? How can I find the Java compiler executable that is used?

I'm omitting any Ant snippets or the like for now, since they are very complex and I'm not a 100% sure which parts are relevant. If you like to see a certain part, please tell me in the comments.

**EDIT**

New insights so far thanks to Robert:

There are a few `taskdef`. Most of them refer to a class in a jar, implementing `Task`. None of them import any compiler-related packages. However there is also ant-contrib loaded as a library:

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${ant.home}/lib/ant-contrib.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

I'm not familiar with this library but it seems to contain some tasks, that could do the compiling. `CompileWithWalls` imports `org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac`. But the `compilewithwalls` target is not called in the Ant scripts. The question remains: If a compiler is used from any of those libraries, how would it be bound to the default `javac` task?

Comment: Are there custom libraries loaded into ANT (custom task or may be custom definitions of variables)?

Comment: @Robert yes, there are a few `taskdef`. They all refer to a class in a jar. I skimmed through those classes but couldn't find anything that looks like a compiler call. What would I be looking for?

Comment: If I had to implement an embedded compiler into ANT I would select the Eclipse compiler. Therefore look for the package `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler`.

Comment: @Robert see my edit

Comment: If a static analysis does not work, try a dynamic one. Run it and monitor it at  runtime. Use inotifytools (Linux) or ProcessMonitor (Win) to check the accessed files.

Comment: @Robert the mystery has been solved. Thanks for the help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague of mine finally solved the mystery.

What I did know was, that Ant uses the JDK located under `JAVA_HOME`. I was however, under the wrong assumption, that Ant uses `javac.exe` to compile. Well, it does not. Ant uses `sun.tools.javac.Main` which is located in the `tools.jar`. That Jar, as well as `javac.exe` only comes with a JDK, but in my case it was included in the products SDK and manually added to the classpath of Ant.

Further reading: http://mindprod.com/jgloss/javacmain.html

Comment: @dertoni I will but I have to wait 2 days before I can